# SQL Server min max with intermediate record

Tags: sql-server, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I am sorry if this question has been answered before, but I cannot find it. Perhaps of my bad keywords.

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 
(
    Employee VARCHAR(10),
    Band VARCHAR(10),
    StartDate DATE,
    EndDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO test1 
VALUES ('Emp1', 'Band1', '2009-01-01', '2010-12-31'),
       ('Emp1', 'Band1', '2011-01-01', '2012-12-31'), 
       ('Emp1', 'Band1', '2013-01-01', '2013-08-31'),
       ('Emp1', 'Band2', '2013-09-01', '2013-12-31'),
       ('Emp1', 'Band2', '2014-01-01', '2014-06-30'),
       ('Emp1', 'Band1', '2014-07-01', '2014-12-31'),
       ('Emp1', 'Band1', '2015-01-01', '2018-08-31'),
       ('Emp2', 'Band1', '2012-01-01', '2014-12-31'),
       ('Emp2', 'Band1', '2015-01-01', '2018-03-31')
```

Results in this table:

```
Employee   Band   StartDate   EndDate
----------------------------------------
Emp1       Band1  2009-01-01  2010-12-31
Emp1       Band1  2011-01-01  2012-12-31
Emp1       Band1  2013-01-01  2013-08-31
Emp1       Band2  2013-09-01  2013-12-31
Emp1       Band2  2014-01-01  2014-06-30
Emp1       Band1  2014-07-01  2014-12-31
Emp1       Band1  2015-01-01  2018-08-31
Emp2       Band1  2012-01-01  2014-12-31
Emp2       Band1  2015-01-01  2018-03-31
```

What I want to create is a result table grouping each `employee` with the `band` and the minimum `start date` and maximum `end date`, but when an *intermediate record (`band`)* exist in the middle between the similar `band`, the `end date` should be capped and the `start date` of the next group in similar `band` should reset again.

```
Employee   Band   StartDate   EndDate
----------------------------------------
Emp1       Band1  2009-01-01  2013-08-31
Emp1       Band2  2013-09-01  2014-06-30
Emp1       Band1  2014-07-01  2018-08-31
Emp2       Band1  2012-01-01  2018-03-31
```

I have tried CTE to get the max and min of each band and compare it with the original table, but I still fail. I also tried using lead and lag but still fail.

***Nice to have***

Supposed the second record's `EndDate` is `2012-02-01`, I prefer the result is still one record for the first Band1 group.

```
Employee   Band   StartDate   EndDate
----------------------------------------
Emp1       Band1  2009-01-01  2013-08-31
```

With each row of the result only differing in `Band`, I would able to figure out how long an employee has stayed in a certain band before moving to other band (different band).

But it is something nice to have.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it and your current attempt. Also, please explain, in words, the logic to get that desired result. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: I hope it is better now.

Comment: Much better. Way to go! What if there are gaps between two records? Suppose the second record would have the start date of `2011-02-01`, should your desired result ignore this gap or should it contain two records for `emp1` and `band1` for these two records in the data?

Comment: Had editted the question. Thanks for pointing out. I would prefer the result to ignore this gap still output one record for the first group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you want to group rows whenever an employee changes band. This is straight forward with window functions. The following solution adds a "change" flag to rows whenever the band changes. Be advised that it ignores gaps. Add DATEDIFF check to the case statement to find the *actual* amount of time the person was associated with a band:

```
DECLARE @test1 TABLE(
    Employee VARCHAR(10),
    Band VARCHAR(10),
    StartDate DATE,
    EndDate DATE
);

INSERT INTO @test1 VALUES
('Emp1', 'Band1', '2009-01-01', '2010-12-31'),
('Emp1', 'Band1', '2011-01-01', '2012-12-31'),
('Emp1', 'Band1', '2013-01-01', '2013-08-31'),
('Emp1', 'Band2', '2013-09-01', '2013-12-31'),
('Emp1', 'Band2', '2014-01-01', '2014-06-30'),
('Emp1', 'Band1', '2014-07-01', '2014-12-31'),
('Emp1', 'Band1', '2015-01-01', '2018-08-31'),
('Emp2', 'Band1', '2012-01-01', '2014-12-31'),
('Emp2', 'Band1', '2015-01-01', '2018-03-31');

WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *,
        CASE WHEN LAG(Band) OVER (PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY StartDate) = Band /* AND DATEDIFF(...) */ THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Chg
    FROM @test1
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT *,
        SUM(Chg) OVER (PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY StartDate) AS Grp
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT Employee, Band, MIN(StartDate), Max(EndDate)
FROM cte2
GROUP BY Employee, Band, Grp
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=94cd885e86b409a655f389cf9c19afab)

This is the intermediate result in case you want to see how it works:

```
| Employee | Band  | StartDate           | EndDate             | Chg | Grp |
|----------|-------|---------------------|---------------------|-----|-----|
| Emp1     | Band1 | 01/01/2009 00:00:00 | 31/12/2010 00:00:00 | 1   | 1   |
| Emp1     | Band1 | 01/01/2011 00:00:00 | 31/12/2012 00:00:00 | 0   | 1   |
| Emp1     | Band1 | 01/01/2013 00:00:00 | 31/08/2013 00:00:00 | 0   | 1   |
| Emp1     | Band2 | 01/09/2013 00:00:00 | 31/12/2013 00:00:00 | 1   | 2   |
| Emp1     | Band2 | 01/01/2014 00:00:00 | 30/06/2014 00:00:00 | 0   | 2   |
| Emp1     | Band1 | 01/07/2014 00:00:00 | 31/12/2014 00:00:00 | 1   | 3   |
| Emp1     | Band1 | 01/01/2015 00:00:00 | 31/08/2018 00:00:00 | 0   | 3   |
| Emp2     | Band1 | 01/01/2012 00:00:00 | 31/12/2014 00:00:00 | 1   | 1   |
| Emp2     | Band1 | 01/01/2015 00:00:00 | 31/03/2018 00:00:00 | 0   | 1   |
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works perfectly with my current problem. For those who need to consider gap between records, John's solution is working great.

Answer (score 1):

This is commonly known as **Gaps and Islands**.

One approach

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Employee] varchar(50),[Band] varchar(50),[Start] date,[End] date)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Emp1','Band1','2009-01-01','2010-12-31')
,('Emp1','Band1','2011-01-01','2012-12-31')
,('Emp1','Band1','2013-01-01','2013-08-31')
,('Emp1','Band2','2013-09-01','2013-12-31')
,('Emp1','Band2','2014-01-01','2014-06-30')
,('Emp1','Band1','2014-07-01','2014-12-31')
,('Emp1','Band1','2015-01-01','2018-08-31')
,('Emp2','Band3','2012-01-01','2014-12-31')
,('Emp2','Band3','2015-01-01','2018-03-31')

;with cte as (
Select *,Grp = sum(Flg) over (Partition By Employee Order by [End])
 From (
        Select *,Flg = IsNull(datediff(DAY,Lag([End],1) over (Partition By Employee,Band Order by [End]) ,[Start]) - 1,1)
         From  @YourTable
      ) A
)
Select Employee
      ,Band
      ,[Start] = min([Start])
      ,[End]   = max([End])
 From cte
 Group By Employee,Band,Grp
 Order by Employee,max([End])
```

**Returns**

```
Employee    Band    Start       End
Emp1        Band1   2009-01-01  2013-08-31
Emp1        Band2   2013-09-01  2014-06-30
Emp1        Band1   2014-07-01  2018-08-31
Emp2        Band3   2012-01-01  2018-03-31
```

If it helps with the visualization, the CTE produces the following

Notice the Flag and Group Columns

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the keyword. Right now I am not be able to access my workstation. I would let you know once I tried your logic. So far I have got the idea based on your solution. I will get back to you in the next 11 hours.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I have tried and it works great when there is a gap between records. However, I need to group them even when a gap exist. I am sorry I did not specify this before. I am sure your answer will help other!